# Edited shapes become invisible

Tags: shapefile, editing, esri-geodatabase, osgeo

I´m working editing shapes in a geodatabase with Osgeo. The last editions become invisible until I make a new edition.

The problem is that the last editions become invisible until I make  a new edition. This happens even through diferent computers, so, is a program problem? There are no error messages. This don´t follow any pattern, sometimes works as expected and sometimes doesn´t. It´s a shp with numerous records (obuot 6000). It have original polygons, than when I modify them it works, the probles is with the new ones. About the symbology, here´s attached a capture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Moat of the time, this is a symbology issue, where the feature is rendered by an attribute which is not present in the symbol table. Please [Edit] the Question to provide more details.

Comment: There´s no problem with the symbologies, but I wonder if there´s a problem with the "objet id" creation, because it occurs only with new polygons.